# Java casting question

Tags: java, casting

I don't understand why I need to cast member variables to the proper type when their types are already declared. For example:

```
public class SomeClass extends SomethingElse {

  private Funky mFunkyVar;
  // a whole bunch of other variables and methods

  public void needToCast() {
    mFunkyVar = (Funky) new FunkySubClass();
  }

}
```

Am I making some newbie mistake or is this indeed idiomatic Java? In the above I'm assuming that FunkySubClass is indeed a subclass of Funky.

Comment: You shouldn't need to if `FunkySubClass` is really a subclass of `Funky`.

Comment: if FunkySubClass extends Funky, then you shouldn't have to cast, no.

Comment: What version of java are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you don't have to cast it!

> *Am I making some newbie mistake*

Yeap, but don't worry... after this you wont do it again ;)

See:

```
$cat Funky.java  
class Funky {
}
class FunkySubClass extends Funky { 
}
class SomethingElse { 
}
class SomeClass extends SomethingElse { 
    private Funky aFunkyVar;
    //...
    public void noNeedToCast() { 
        aFunkyVar = new FunkySubClass();
    }
}

$javac Funky.java 
$
```

No compilation errors.

**EDIT**

You can cast primitives and object references.

**For primitives** you "have" to cast, if you want to narrow the value.

For instance:

```
int i = 255;
byte b = ( byte ) i;
```

If you don't cast the compiler will warn you, "hey, you don't really want to do that"

```
...
byte b = i;
...
Funky.java:18: possible loss of precision
found   : int
required: byte
        byte d = i;
```

Casting is like telling the compiler: "hey don't worry, I know what I'm doing, ok?"

Of course, if you cast, and the value didn't fit, you'll get strange results:

```
int i = 2550;
byte b = ( byte ) i;
System.out.println( b );
```

prints:

```
-10
```

You **don't need to cast** when the type is *wider* than the other type:

```
byte b = 255;
int i = b;// no cast needed
```

**For references** works in a similar fashion.

You need to cast, when you want to go down into the class hierarchy ( narrow ) and you don't need to cast when you want to go upper in the hierarchy ( like in your sample ).

So if we have:

```
   java.lang.Object 
   |
   + -- Funky
        |
        +-- FunkySubclass
```

You only have to cast, when you have a type upper in the hierarchy ( Object or Funky ) in this case.  And you don't have to, if you have a type lower in the hierarchy:

```
void other( Object o ) { 
    // Cast needed:
    Funky f = ( Funky ) o;
    FunkySubClass fsc = ( FunkySubClass ) o;
    FunkySubClass fscII = ( FunkySubClass ) f;
    // Cast not needed:
    Object fobj = f; 
    Object fscobj = fsc; 
    Funky fparent = fsc;
}
```

With primitives the JVM know how to truncate the value, but with reference no. So, if the casted value is **not** of the target type, you'll get a `java.lang.ClassCastException` at runtime. That's the price you have to pay, when you tell the compiler "I know what I'm doing" and you don't.

I hope this is clear enough and don't confuse you.

:)

Comment: Where can I find the rules for casting in Java? The android tutorials cast stuff all over the place and it's just really weird declaring a variable of a certain type and then having to cast it as well.

Comment: @davidk01:Implicit casting can be far more awkward.  Can you imagine not having any compile error when doing: `Object o = "hello"; HashMap h = o;`?  After all, from the compiler's perspective that is the same operation you're attempting, only here it's pretty obviously wrong.

Comment: You have to cast when want to "narrow" the type ( and you have a wider type in the hierachy )... mmhh let me see if I can put something simple enough.

Comment: I think I understand. I'm going to assume all the casting happening in android tutorials are downcasts because it's mostly in the view related code since most view methods just return a View object and in order to work with them properly we need to convert them to Buttons, TextViews, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If FunkySubClass is really a subclass of Funky you don't need the cast.

If you show us the error you're getting we could help more.

Comment: No errors but this type of code shows up in all the android tutorials and the essence of my confusion was seeing a variable declared as Something and then having it cast to Something in some method.

Comment: @davidk01:In that case, @Foo Bah's answer might actually be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

No need to "`(Funky)`", as `FunkySubClass` **is-a** `Funky`.

Comment: ...we think (based on the names)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to explicitly cast to the base class. For example, it is actually more idiomatic not to cast - a common case is:

```
List<String> somelist=new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You would only need to cast if FunkySubClass was (improperly named and) in fact the parent class of Funky. Assigning a child class to a parent object is fine.

Answer (score 0):

`new FunkySubClass()` returns an object of type FunkySubClass, not Funky.  Hence you should explicitly tell Java to treat it as a Funky object

It is the right-hand side which is being converted

Comment: Not true.  An object can be directly assigned to a variable typed as any of it's ancestors.

Comment: Which would be relevant if `FunkySubClass` wasn't a subclass of `Funky`.  But that seems to go against what the names suggest.

Comment: In absentia of the actual definition, I presumed the author tried the code without the cast.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to cast it. What makes you think you do?